# Show 'Free' if the price is 0.00 in Easy digital download

Tags: php, price, easy-digital-downloads

I want to show 'Free' if the price is 0.00. Could you guys check my code below is it correct?

```
<?php edd_price($download_id = 0); ?>
if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) {
?>Free
```

Comment: I don't know how the rest of your code looks, but from seeing this part, you are missing the inside of the if clause and an } at the end, before closing the php clause. Also, you have closed the php clause in the first line and then close it again in the third.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about EDD but your code has syntax issues:

```
<?php edd_price($download_id = 0); ?>
if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) {
?>Free
```

Here, `if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 )` is not enclosed by `<?php` tag. You should remove the `?>` in the line before. Also, you are missing the closing braces for you `if`.Not sure if thats because you have more codes that you did not show here.

Update:

As per the comment below, the code should be updated as below:

```
<?php if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) { ?>
    <h5>Free</h5></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. the actual code is like below : 

<span class="col-2"><h5><?php edd_price($download_id = 0); ?></h5>
    if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) {
   <h5>Free</h5></span>
 } ?>


but i've another problem which is it doesn't hide $0.00 price . really need your help this time.

Comment: `</h5> if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) { <h5>Free</h5></span> } ?>` should be `</h5> <?php if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) { ?><h5>Free</h5></span><?php } ?>`

Comment: is this correct? now it display blank page : 


<span class="col-2"><h5><?php edd_price($download_id = 0); ?></h5>
   <?php if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) {
   <h5>Free</h5></span>
 } ?>

Comment: try this and see what output you get: `<?php if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) { ?><h5>Free</h5></span><?php } else { ?><h5><?= edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) ?></h5><?php } ?>`

Comment: `<h5>Free</h5></span>` should be `?><h5>Free</h5></span><?php`

Comment: You are welcome. If this works for you, please mark this as the correct answer.